# Extract repeated Date & Time from columns (SQL-DataTable) and Display them as Column Heading on MVC Web App

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, datatable, pivot

I am new to the programming. I have created a web application (MVC4) which displays the table from SQL like:

```
----------------------------------
Wavelength | Values | Date | Time
----------------------------------
228        | 0      |10 Oct| 9:00
229        | 0.5    |10 Oct| 9:00
.            .       .       .
.            .       .       .
.            .       .       .
228        | 0.1    |11 Oct| 8:00
229        | 0.3    |11 Oct| 8:00
.            .       .       .
.            .       .       .
.            .       .       .
228        | 0.6    |11 Oct| 10:00
229        | 0.2    |11 Oct| 10:00
----------------------------------
```

How can I display it like:

```
-------------------------------------
           | 10 Oct |     11 Oct        
           --------------------------
Wavelength | 09:00  | 08:00  | 10:00
           --------------------------
           | Values | Values | Values 
-------------------------------------
228        | 0      | 0.1    | 0.6  
229        | 0.5    |  0.3   | 0.2 
------------------------------------
```

Should I go for Dynamic SQL Pivot or it can achieved by some client side technique. suggestions please.

I,m sorry if you found this question as not specific.

Thank you :)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Why are you keeping date and time in a  separate column is there any specific reason for that

Comment: Actually, this Date and Time is provided by user (when uploading file containing data to the server), this Date and Time is related to when the data has been taken/noted.

Comment: were you able to check the solution @rizkhan

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran thank you for the answer, unfortunately for some reasons I wasn't able to run the query for long time, sorry for that. The solution you provided worked perfectly. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can do dynamic pivoting, this code was tested in sql server,

```
 declare @allval varchar(500) 
 declare @sql varchar(500)

create table #table (wavelength varchar(50), value decimal(2,2), [date] varchar(10), [time] varchar(10))


insert into #table values
(228 ,0,'10 oct','9:00'),
(229 ,0.5,'10 oct','9:00'),
(228 ,0.1,'11 oct','8:00'),
(229 ,0.3,'11 oct','8:00'),
(228 ,0.6,'11 oct','10:00'),
(229 ,0.2,'11 oct','10:00')

select @allval = (select  Stuff((SELECT distinct ', ' + concat('[',date,' ',time,']')
         FROM #table l
         FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') )



 select @sql = 'select * from
(select concat(date,'' '',time) as datetime,wavelength,value from #table )j
pivot (max(value)
for [datetime] in(' + @allval+ '))p'

exec(@sql)

drop table #table
```